# Get user's email address from Twitter with C# and OAuth

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, oauth, tweetsharp

I have my app whitelisted on Twitter now to be able to obtain their email address when they log in and I'm using TweetSharp as my library to authenticate users, but I don't see a way to pass in the parameter to request their email address using that library.  I know it's an old library and I think that the requesting user's email is relatively new so maybe it's just not possible w/o digging through the source, updating it and recompiling the assembly?

If anyone has been able to accomplish this with TweetSharp, please let me know.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the source of TweetSharp a bit, I got fairly lost in the layer upon layer upon layer...like trying to find a needle in 20 haystacks.  I appreciate the link to Tweetinvi Linvi, but I decided to exercise my brain a bit this evening and see if I could write it up from scratch.

I spent some time looking over what I could find on Twitter and the way they do OAuth is beyond funky.  I then found a PHP solution that handles the OAuth and tweaked it a bit to make it return the email address.  Armed with that, I translated the PHP to C# and got it all working in my own home baked solution.

I just posted my working solution here: http://www.burritostand.com/log-in-to-twitter-with-oauth-and-c-sharp-and-get-twitter-user-email

It needs some major refactoring to make it a production-worthy implementation, but I thought it might be useful to others as it breaks down the different processes pretty clearly.  Hopefully someone else can make use of it.

The critical piece (for retrieving the email) is in the TwitterClient class, in the parameter list:

```
        TwitterUrls TwitterUrls = new TwitterUrls("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json");
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("include_email", "true")); // this is the important part for getting the email returned
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_consumer_key", ConsumerKey));
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_nonce", Nonce));
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"));
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_timestamp", timestamp));
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_token", dict["oauth_token"]));
        Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_version", OAuthVersion));
```

I appreciate the answers and I did have some fun going back to PHP tonight...been a looooong time :)

Answer (score 1):

Tweetinvi supports email.

```
var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
var email = authenticatedUser.Email;
```

You can find the project on github here : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi